Trying to Color code Sparkline bar graph in Google sheets but getting unexpected errors
I am color coding my sparklines bar graph based on percentage cutoffs and get formula parse errors.This gets an error
=SPARKLINE((E6/F6),{"charttype","bar";"max",1; "min",0;color1",IF((E6/F6)>0.9,"blue",IF((E6/F6)>0.7,"green",IF((E6/F6)>0.5,"yellow","red"))})
while this works.
=SPARKLINE((E6/F6),{"charttype","bar";"max",1; "min",0;color1",IF((E6/F6)>0.9,"blue",IF((E6/F6)>0.7,"green","yellow"))})
The only difference I spot is how many IFs I have.  Is there some limit to the number of ifs you can nest or am I missing something else?
I have tried starting from the beginning and adding one IF at a time but when I reach a certain point it just stops working


There seems to be slight mismatch with the if() closing brackets:
=SPARKLINE((E6/F6),{"charttype","bar";"max",1; "min",0;"color1",IF((E6/F6)>0.9,"blue",IF((E6/F6)>0.7,"green",IF((E6/F6)>0.5,"yellow","red")))})



Could have sworn I tried that.  Thank you.
